# i can get text input value just for 1 time

Tags: javascript

i have a form with 4 input. i need to get the values of this form inputs when user click on button. i use following codes. but only at the first time after page loading the values of text inputs return. for second time the value of drop down input return correctly but the function return null for text input values.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- برای فارسی نویسی حتما این تگ وارد شود -->
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <form name="insuranceData">
            total: <input name="totalPrice" type="text" size="10"/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            prePayment: <input name="prePayment" type="text" size="10"/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            peyments number: <select name="numberOfPeyments">       
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input name="paymentsCalculat" value="محاسبه اقساط" type="button" size="10" onClick="checkInputs();"/>
            
            <div id="paymentsTableDiv" style="display:none">
                <table width="40%" align="center" dir="rtl" id="paymentsTable" style="text-align:center;">
                    <tr bgcolor="red"><th>شماره قسط</th><th>مبلغ قسط</th><th>تاریخ سررسید</th><th>توضیحات</th></tr>                     
                </table>            
            </div>
    
            
        </form>
                
                
        <script type="text/javascript">
                
            function getFormValues(){
                var numberOfPeyments = document.forms["insuranceData"]["numberOfPeyments"].value;
                var totalPrice = document.forms["insuranceData"]["totalPrice"].value;
                var prePayment = document.forms["insuranceData"]["prePayment"].value;
    
                return [numberOfPeyments,totalPrice,prePayment,];
                }
            
            function checkInputs(){
                insuranceParams=getFormValues();
                if (insuranceParams[1]==""){
                    alert("مبلغ کل حق بیمه را وارد نمایید ");
                }else if (insuranceParams[2]==""){
                    alert("مبلغ پیش پرداخت را وارد نمایید ");
                }else{
                    if(parseInt(insuranceParams[1]) > parseInt(insuranceParams[2])){
                    createPaymentsTable();
                    }else{
                        alert("مبلغ پیش پرداخت نباید از مبلغ کل حق بیمه بیشتر باشد!");
                    }
                }                                   
            }
            
            function createPaymentsTable(){
                var insuranceParams=getFormValues();
                var remindeValue=insuranceParams[1]-insuranceParams[2];
                var ValueOfAnyPayments=remindeValue/insuranceParams[0];             
                                
                document.getElementById("paymentsTableDiv").style.display = 'block';
                                
                for (i=1;i<=parseInt(insuranceParams[0]);i++){
                    var newRow=document.getElementById('paymentsTable').insertRow();
                    newRow.innerHTML = "<td>"+i+"</td>"+
                    "<td><input id='DEMO' dir='ltr' name='prePayment' type='text' size='10' value='"+ValueOfAnyPayments+"'/></td>"+
                    "<td>"+i+"</td>"+
                    "<td><input dir='rtl' name='prePayment' type='text' size='10'/></td>";                  
                }
                                
            }
                
                
        </script>   
                
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you have 3 inputs... and you want the values of all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why you are not getting any values by `document.forms` but you could fix this problem by using `document.querySelector` instead.

Have a look below

```js
function getFormValues() {
  var numberOfPeyments = document.querySelector("[name=insuranceData] [name=numberOfPeyments]").value;
  var totalPrice = document.querySelector("[name=insuranceData] [name=totalPrice]").value
  var prePayment = document.querySelector("[name=insuranceData] [name=prePayment]").value
  console.clear();
  console.log([numberOfPeyments, totalPrice, prePayment, ])
  return [numberOfPeyments, totalPrice, prePayment, ];
}

function checkInputs() {
  insuranceParams = getFormValues();
  if (insuranceParams[1] == "") {
    alert("مبلغ کل حق بیمه را وارد نمایید ");
  } else if (insuranceParams[2] == "") {
    alert("مبلغ پیش پرداخت را وارد نمایید ");
  } else {
    if (parseInt(insuranceParams[1]) > parseInt(insuranceParams[2])) {
      createPaymentsTable();
    } else {
      alert("مبلغ پیش پرداخت نباید از مبلغ کل حق بیمه بیشتر باشد!");
    }
  }
}

function createPaymentsTable() {
  var insuranceParams = getFormValues();
  var remindeValue = insuranceParams[1] - insuranceParams[2];
  var ValueOfAnyPayments = remindeValue / insuranceParams[0];

  document.getElementById("paymentsTableDiv").style.display = 'block';

  for (i = 1; i <= parseInt(insuranceParams[0]); i++) {
    var newRow = document.getElementById('paymentsTable').insertRow();
    newRow.innerHTML = "<td>" + i + "</td>" +
      "<td><input id='DEMO' dir='ltr' name='prePayment' type='text' size='10' value='" + ValueOfAnyPayments + "'/></td>" +
      "<td>" + i + "</td>" +
      "<td><input dir='rtl' name='prePayment' type='text' size='10'/></td>";
  }

}
```

```html
<form name="insuranceData">
  total: <input name="totalPrice" type="text" size="10" />
  <br/>
  <br/> prePayment: <input name="prePayment" type="text" size="10" />
  <br/>
  <br/> peyments number:
  <select name="numberOfPeyments">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input name="paymentsCalculat" value="محاسبه اقساط" type="button" size="10" onClick="checkInputs();" />

  <div id="paymentsTableDiv" style="display:none">
    <table width="40%" align="center" dir="rtl" id="paymentsTable" style="text-align:center;">
      <tr bgcolor="red">
        <th>شماره قسط</th>
        <th>مبلغ قسط</th>
        <th>تاریخ سررسید</th>
        <th>توضیحات</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

By catching elements [`document.getElementById("myForm").elements;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements), you can read form's values. Also there is no need to call `getFormValues()` function for the second time from the `createPaymentsTable()` function. You can pass values while calling `getFormValues()` from the `checkInputs()` function. Have a look at the snippet below:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- برای فارسی نویسی حتما این تگ وارد شود -->
</head>

<body>

    <form name="insuranceData" id="myForm">
        total: <input name="totalPrice" type="text" size="10" />
        <br />
        <br />
        prePayment: <input name="prePayment" type="text" size="10" />
        <br />
        <br />
        peyments number: <select name="numberOfPeyments">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input name="paymentsCalculat" value="محاسبه اقساط" type="button" size="10" onClick="checkInputs();" />

        <div id="paymentsTableDiv" style="display:none">
            <table width="40%" align="center" dir="rtl" id="paymentsTable" style="text-align:center;">
                <tr bgcolor="red">
                    <th>شماره قسط</th>
                    <th>مبلغ قسط</th>
                    <th>تاریخ سررسید</th>
                    <th>توضیحات</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>




    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getFormValues() {
            var fields = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
            var numberOfPeyments = fields[0].value;
            var totalPrice = fields[1].value;
            var prePayment = fields[2].value;

            console.log(numberOfPeyments, totalPrice, prePayment);

            return [numberOfPeyments, totalPrice, prePayment];
        }

        function checkInputs() {
            var insuranceParams = getFormValues();
            if (insuranceParams[1] == "") {
                alert("مبلغ کل حق بیمه را وارد نمایید ");
            } else if (insuranceParams[2] == "") {
                alert("مبلغ پیش پرداخت را وارد نمایید ");
            } else {
                if (parseInt(insuranceParams[1]) > parseInt(insuranceParams[2])) {
                    createPaymentsTable(insuranceParams);
                } else {
                    alert("مبلغ پیش پرداخت نباید از مبلغ کل حق بیمه بیشتر باشد!");
                }
            }
        }

        function createPaymentsTable(insuranceParams) {
            // var insuranceParams = getFormValues();
            var remindeValue = insuranceParams[1] - insuranceParams[2];
            var ValueOfAnyPayments = remindeValue / insuranceParams[0];

            document.getElementById("paymentsTableDiv").style.display = 'block';

            for (i = 1; i <= parseInt(insuranceParams[0]); i++) {
                var newRow = document.getElementById('paymentsTable').insertRow();
                newRow.innerHTML = "<td>" + i + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input id='DEMO' dir='ltr' name='prePayment' type='text' size='10' value='" + ValueOfAnyPayments + "'/></td>" +
                    "<td>" + i + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input dir='rtl' name='prePayment' type='text' size='10'/></td>";
            }

        }


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so tanks. but i can't put table out of form. because i need to import some input in this table that must send with form.

Comment: @HadiTaj, Got it, updated the answer now. You can have a look.